# Redux store state is not updating when calling Object.assign in React-Native

Tags: react-native, redux, websocket

I am developing an application on React Native.

Here's my code, `UPDATE_MY_CONNECTION_ID` works as intended and updates the state when dispatched. `UPDATE_ROOM` however, does not update the state at all. It can reach the `console.log(tmp)` line

```
const initialState = {
  playerOne: "",
  playerTwo: "",
  connectionIdArr: [],
  myConnectionId: "",
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_MY_CONNECTION_ID":
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        myConnectionId: action.payload.myConnectionId,
      });
    case "UPDATE_ROOM":
      console.log(
        "updating room after receiving broadcast from room player",
        action.payload
      );
      Axios.get(
        `${process.env.API_ENDPOINT}/get_room/${action.payload.match_id}`
      )
        .then((res) => {
          const tmp = {};
          if (res.data.players[0] && res.data.players[0].length > 0)
            tmp.playerOne = res.data.players[0];
          if (res.data.players[1] && res.data.players[1].length > 0)
            tmp.playerTwo = res.data.players[1];
          tmp.connectionIdArr = [...res.data.connections];
          console.log(tmp);
          return Object.assign({}, state, tmp);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log("error UPDATE_ROOM: ", err));
    default:
       etc etc etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use async requests into the reducer, if you really want to do async requests , redux-thunk is a good choice or redux-saga. I sugest you take a look at both and choose the one that fits for your needs.

[Redux-Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/)

[Redux-Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)